# Android - ListView not animating while Loading

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using [this](https://github.com/twotoasters/JazzyListView/) library for adding an **AnimatedListView** to my app. But, the `ListView` gets animated only when I scroll up or down the `ListView`. I want it to get animated while being loaded too. Please help me with any possible suggestion to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What about download the source and edit it? Or something similar?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I tried your suggestion but I discovered that it's `JazzyListView` class extends the `ListView` class. But then, how do I get the `ListView` to animate item population?

Comment: What you mean with "being loaded" ? I mean: while you download something it should show an animation every time an item is added?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno By "being loaded", I mean populating the `Listview`. It doesn't show any animation while initial loading(populating) the `ListView`.

Comment: So you want to show an animation when you add the item.. I don't know how the AnimatedListView works but you could save in a boolean if it's the first time the ListView asks for the view (maybe using the position? firstTime[position] true => already added, maybe now the user is scroll let default AnimatedList do his work, false first time it asks for this position so show for your animation)